# Data frame Manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, swap

I have the following dataframe named stations  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOo44.png. I also have the two vectors from<- 1 147 141 8  and  to<-147 141 8 17. As you can see in the data frame, the columns "from" and "to" do not match up with the vector. This is causing the longitude and latitude columns of the route to be backwards. For example, instead of going from San Francisco to Portland, it is going from Portland to San Francisco. In order to fix this I would have to reverse the order of the dataframe columns that do not match up with my vectors. So my data frame should start at row 125 and go to 116 in order to correct the route. This would need to be done for all the columns of the data frame where the "from" and "to" colulmns do not match up with the from and to vectors. I am sorry if this was not the best explanation, but this a difficult topic to explain.

EDIT: Here is a reproducible code of the what the current structure is

```
current<-data.frame(ID= c(116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125), 
 from = c(147,147,147,147,147,147,147,147,147,147),to = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),lon=c(-122.6742,-122.6402,-122.6267,-122.5792,-122.5634,-122.5401,-122.5199,-122.5081,-122.4775,-122.4415), 
 lat= c(45.52025, 44.48824, 44.07356, 42.62986, 42.14788, 41.44040, 40.58136,40.46431 ,39.53378, 38.43697))
```

and what i want

```
Final<-data.frame(ID= c(125,124,123,122,121,120,119,118,117,116), 
                  from = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), to = c(147,147,147,147,147,147,147,147,147,147),lon=c(-122.4415, -122.4775, -122.5081 ,-122.5199, -122.5401, -122.5634, -122.5792,-122.6267, -122.6402, -122.6742), 
                 lat= c(38.43697 ,39.53378, 40.46431, 40.58136, 41.44040, 42.14788 ,42.62986,44.07356, 44.48824, 45.52025))
```

The changing of the structure should be based on the detection of vectors from and to not matching the columns in the current data frame.

```
from<-1 147 141 8
to<-147 141 8 17
```

Any tips help would help greatly, thank you.

Comment: I added reproducible code of what the current structure is and what the final structure should be. Again, I am trying to get it to detect that it does not match with the vectors, and that is when I would like to restructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing backwards:

```
df[116:125,] <- df[125:116,]
```

Example (df is a data frame of length 8):

```
> df$nums <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
> df[2:5,] <- df[5:2,]
> df$nums
[1] 1 5 4 3 2 6 7 8
```

However, you will still then need to change the to/from vectors in these cases back to the original formats or it will still be backwards if I'm reading correctly.  Let me know if I properly understood your question.

Comment: yes, thank you ,  indexing backwards would solve part of the issue. Although I would need to be able to tell which columns to index backwards. I tried running a for loop in order to tell me which columns need to be flipped with no luck.

Comment: Can you give more examples of sets of columns that need to be flipped?  What criteria do you use manually to determine which columns need to be flipped?

Comment: Yes, so if we treat the two vectors "from" and "to" as points so (1,147) , that means from node 1 to node 147. The second "point" would be (147,141), from node 147 to node 141. Then (141,8) and (8,17). Instead of showing from 1 to 147 , the dataframe has from 147 to 1. This is the case also for the second point, instead of from 147 to 141 , it shows 141 to 147. Same for the third, it should be from 141 to 8 but it shows 8 to 141. The only correct set in the DF is from 8 to 17.

Comment: Okay.  If there's only one correct set in the DF, my suggestion would be to excise it, swap the direction for the rest of it using backwards indexing, and then put the correct set back in.  Would that work?